# Why don't I get any CSS output?

Tags: 8, theming, .htaccess

I did a fresh install of Drupal 8.
Everything had a nice style while installing, but when it was done, there was no CSS anymore.
Did the installation change some file rights?

- I tried flushing the cache
- I did check if the core/theme folder has CSS files in it
- I did a re-install, but again there is just raw HTML

I checked and it looks like I have an HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error on all CSS and JavaScript files.

Update:
The issue is with the .htaccess file in /sites/default/files/.htaccess
I changed the permission of the file to 644, then once changed,
i did edit the file via the file manager and commented out these lines:

#Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews php_flag engine off

It works now but is tis a safe way to do it?

Comment: try flushing the cache. Check if the core/theme folder has css file on it. I don't think file rights should affect css from being outputted as long as the css got uploaded. If not, try installing again.

Comment: Inspect the page source for the style sheet source, copy url and try to navigate to it in new browser window. Take it from there.

Comment: See if your files directory has proper permissions(is writable by drupal).

Comment: What is the contents of the 500 response? If you switch error reporting on from config > development > logging you should see the error in the response

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this in the apache error log:

```
.../sites/default/files/.htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here
```

Checking `.htaccess`, I found:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
```

Even though it's turning `MultiViews` off, it's still not allowed, and removing it fixed the CSS.
Enabling sites to set it int he global apache config would also resolve it.